# exam.cls package change grid color

Tags: color, exam, grids

I'd like to change the **grid color in the exam.cls package**. By default, it seems to be black (although in the documentation it says the default color is gray). Anyway, I would like to have **a very light gray**, but defining a new color doesn't seem to change anything.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{GridColor}{rgb}{0.75, 0.75, 0.75}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{questions}

    \addpoints
    \question[1] Schreibe unten hin was immer du willst.

    \fillwithgrid{\stretch{1}}
    \newpage

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the manual states, you have to issue the `\colorgrids` macro right after `\usepackage{color}`.

[image: close up of light grey grid]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\usepackage{color}
\colorgrids
%\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{GridColor}{rgb}{0.75, 0.75, 0.75}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{questions}

    \addpoints
    \question[1] Schreibe unten hin was immer du willst.

    \fillwithgrid{\stretch{1}}
    \newpage

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh of course... How did I miss that? Thanks!